# Flutter : How to fix InkWell() Tap effects when it's child is container

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to trigger InkWell tap effects when it's child is container but it didn't work.so obviously the question is how to show some tap effets when tapping on InkWell.
This is the code:

```
InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: isAvailable!
                    ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 118, 0, 1)
                    : Color.fromRGBO(114, 114, 114, 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              width: (MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .width - 60) / 2,
              height: 50,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Request',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ink animations are happening when you tap but it's not showing because it's behind the container, so I modified a little on your code by removing the container, and introduced the Ink widget

**Solution 1 :**

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Ink(
        
        width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60) / 2,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isAvailable
              ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 118, 0, 1)
              : Color.fromRGBO(114, 114, 114, 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Request',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

***Solution 2 : by re-ordering the widgets***

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isAvailable
              ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 118, 0, 1)
              : Color.fromRGBO(114, 114, 114, 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60) / 2,
        height: 50,
        child: Material(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Request',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: allah ya7mi algeria :)